# Java, Substring to get value from string

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

given a string like this

```
string a = "Course Name:\n" + CourseName
                         +"\n\nVenue:\n" + locationName
                         +"\n\nStart Time:\n" + startTime 
                         +"\n\nEnd Time:\n"+ endTime";
```

`CourseName`,`locationName`,`startTime` and `endTime` would be a variable and being assigned to `string` a, how can i get all these value from the string using `substring` or regex and store all of it into different variable? please note that I don't have access all these variable, I can only access the string which leave me the only option is play around with `substring` or `regex`.

Comment: Could you add an example value for `a` please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could split by newline

```
String[] parts = a.split("\\n");
String courseName = parts[1];
String locationName = parts[4];
String startTime= parts[7];
String endTime= parts[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use:

```
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(a, "\n");

while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());
        }
```